# Google Compute Engine: Create load balancer for already created VM's

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have set of webserver VM's running on Google Compute Engine VM's,
upon which I need to apply a load-balancer.

When I tried to create load-balancer in Google Cloud Console, its asking for backend service, which require an instance-group to be given.

But I am unable to create an instance group upon already created VM's. Creating an instance group will create new fresh VM's as per the specification, which I dont want.

Please help me to know, is there any other way to create load-balancer upon existing VM's

Comment: Can you stop the instances, take a private image of one of them (assuming they're all basically the same thing), create a instance group, then launch new instances into that group from the previously-saved image?

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have is to create an "unmanaged instance group".

This is a group of VMs that you manage yourself and only supports load balancing.
There is no neccesary to shutdown or stop your vm's to create it but as you can see there are some disvantages vs. "managed instace groups":

- autoscaling, autohealing, auto-updating.
- multi-zone deployment.